# Overload Functions For Different Structs Implementing The Same Protocol?

Tags: swift, generics, overloading

I'm new to statically typed languages and was wondering if it was possible to cast a Struct to its type in order to call the proper overloaded function? The issue I'm running into to is I have a list of Structs that conform to a `Mutation` protocol. I want to iterate through the list and call the correct `handle` function for each Struct. I could move this `handle` function to the Struct itself, but for the API I'm trying to implement I'd like to see if such a thing is possible as below:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

protocol Mutation {
    func mutate(state: Int) -> Int
}

struct CountIncrement: Mutation {
    func mutate(state: Int) -> Int {
        return state + 1
    }
}

struct CountDecrement: Mutation {
    func mutate(state: Int) -> Int {
        return state - 1
    }
}

func handle(mutation: CountIncrement, state: Int) -> Int {
    print("WILL INCREMENT")
    return mutation.mutate(state: state)
}

func handle(mutation: CountDecrement, state: Int) -> Int {
    print("WILL DECREMENT")
    return mutation.mutate(state: state)
}

var state = 0
var queue = [CountIncrement(), CountDecrement()] as [Mutation]

for mutation in queue {
    handle(mutation: mutation, state: state) // error: cannot invoke 'handle' with an argument list of type '(mutation: Mutation, state: Int)'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is backwards of how you should approach the problem. In Swift you should generally avoid free functions (like `handle(mutation:state:)`), and instead attach methods to types.

Your loop wants a specific method, so you want a new protocol (you could of course attach this function to `Mutation`, but making it separate means that it could have different access controls or the like, so is as flexible as the free functions).

```
protocol MutationHandling {
    func handleMutation(forState state: Int) -> Int
}
```

So we've just declared that this function you want is a thing. Now we can attach it to things that we care about. This is exactly the same as your writing free-functions above. It's the same pattern. The syntax is just different, and provides some extra documentation about why this function exists and allows the IDE to provide auto-completion and gather documentation together more effectively.

```
extension CountIncrement: MutationHandling {
    func handleMutation(forState state: Int) -> Int {
        print("WILL INCREMENT")
        return mutate(state: state)
    }
}
```

Now, you use this special protocol for your list:

```
var queue = [CountIncrement(), CountDecrement()] as [MutationHandling]
```

And call it:

```
for mutation in queue {
    mutation.handleMutation(forState: state)
}
```

This isn't just some random limitation in Swift. This is a deep part of how Swift decomposes problems. Free-functions are explicitly discouraged (see the [API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/)). Methods and extensions are the Swift way.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine your `handle()` functions like this and accept for the parameter `mutation` all objects that conform to your protocol `Mutation`:

```
func handle(mutation: Mutation, state: Int) -> Int {
    return mutation.mutate(state: state)
}
```

---

The reason for this:

`queue` is of the type `[Mutating]`. Because of that, `mutation` in your for-Loop will be `Mutation`. And currently, you have no `handle()` function, that accepts `Mutation` as parameter.